# ASP.NET Core 2.1 Routing - CreatedAtRoute - No route matches the supplied values

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I have the following situation

```cs
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class FooController: ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetFoo")]
    public ActionResult<FooBindModel> Get([FromRoute]Guid id)
    {
        // ...
    }
}

[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class Foo2Controller: ControllerBase
{

    [HttpPost("/api/Foo2/Create")]
    public ActionResult<GetFooBindModel> Create([FromBody]PostFooBindModel postBindModel)
    {
        //...
        return CreatedAtRoute("GetFoo", new { id = getBindModel.Id }, getBindModel);

    }
}
```

PS: `getBindModel` is an instance of type `GetFooBindModel`. And I am getting

> InvalidOperationException: No route matches the supplied values.

I also tried changing the line

```
return CreatedAtRoute("GetFoo", new { id = getBindModel.Id }, getBindModel);
```

to

```
return CreatedAtRoute("api/Foo/GetFoo", new { id = getBindModel.Id }, getBindModel);
```

but still the same error.

Comment: What is the version for `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core`? I made a test with default `Asp.Net Core MVC 2.1` template by adding the same controller like yours, but I fail to reproduce your issue. Is there any reproducable project through github?

Comment: try `new { getBindModel.Id}` remove the `Id`

Answer (score 7):

Match the name of your action method (Get) in the *FooController* with the route name on HttpGet Attribute. You can use the nameof keyword in c#:

```
[HttpGet("{id}", Name = nameof(Get))]
public ActionResult<FooBindModel> Get([FromRoute]Guid id)
{
          ...
}
```

and also Instead of hard coding route name use *nameof* again:

```
return CreatedAtRoute(nameof(FooController.Get), new { id = getBindModel.Id }, getBindModel);
```

and Try again;

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me:

```
return CreatedAtRoute(
          "GetFoo", 
          new { controller = "Foo", id = getBindModel.Id}, 
          getBindModel);
```